# Accessing AppIcon and Launch Image from SPM Package

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I have a SPM with some assets in `Assets-Target.xcassets`. I have app Icon there and Launch Screen Icon. After integrating into main application, I am unable to access the LaunchImage in the BuildSettings Asset Catalog Launch Image Set Name. Any Help with this is appriticated.

This is my Package.swift

```
let package = Package(
    name: "XXXX",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v11)],
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "XXXX",
            targets: ["XXXX"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "XXXX",
            dependencies: [
            ],
            resources: [
                .process("Resources")
            ]
        ),
        .testTarget(
            name: "XXXXTests",
            dependencies: ["XXXX"]
        ),
        
    ]
)
```

The assets is under a Resources folder.

Comment: If you want to use AppIcon or LaunchImage from your`Assets-Target.xcassets` you should add it into your project. Resources from SPM can be accessible in runtime only via the package's bundle that is integrated to your app.

Comment: I understand this but having access to it in Build Settings is what I want to do.

Comment: Hi @iUrii I would appreciate if you could help contribute here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67907955/modifying-file-in-path-spm